# Ожидаемое условие не выполнено: ожидание видимости всех элементов, расположенных с помощью By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium, maven, тестирование, автоматизация

Падает тест,  ошибка: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: ожидаемое условие не выполнено: ожидание видимости всех элементов, расположенных с помощью By.xpath: //h5[text()='Elements'] (попытка длилась 30 секунд с интервалом 500 миллисекунд)

Использую Java, Selenium, openJDK, Maven.
Сайт, который тестирую (использую для обучения автоматизации тестирования) - https://demoqa.com/

Я хочу, что бы этот сайт открылся в браузере и кликнуть по разделу Elements.
Так  и происходит - сайт открывается и кликается раздел Elements. После этого тест падает.

Код (вынесен в отдельный класс):

```
 public void chooseElements(String Elenents) {
        click(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Elements']"));
    }
```

В самом тесте код такой:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void FirstTest() {
        main.goTo(); /* обращаемся к странице MainPage */
        main.chooseElements("Elements");
       elements.checkPageIsCorrect();
    }
```

Не понимаю, что не так. Прошу помочь с решением проблемы.

Comment: А что-за метод click такой?

Comment: у меня метод записан так:    /* 7. Click Method - нажать на элемент */
    public void click(By elementBy) {
        waitVisibility(elementBy);
        driver.findElement(elementBy).click();
    }